# how to collect latest launched instance information in aws cloud using ec2-api tool?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I need latest launched instance information in aws cloud using  ec2-api tool.
 i need a information like instance id,launchedtime,reservation no and etc.

Answer (score 1):

AWS has released their own CLI that works on any platform (Windows, Mac, Linux). 
http://aws.amazon.com/cli/
Once downloaded, installed and configured:

```
aws configure
```

You can use

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
aws ec2 describe-instances help
```

to get what you need